# moving website to doteasy - best place to put database constants? 

Tags: php, document-root

This is my first time moving a locally-hosted PHP site to a hosting service. My site is built with the inc folder (which includes the database constants) outside of the web root, so on my local machine it's in

```
XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inc/
```

and the rest of the files, including the common/ directory, are in

```
XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydomain/
```

Most of the pages call

```
include_once "common/base.php";
```

which lives inside

```
htdocs/mydomain/common/
```

and which includes the database constants by calling

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/inc/constants.inc.php";
```

On my local site, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] outputs "Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/", and the inc files are found.

Unfortunately, on the DotEasy site, the files aren't being found. If I echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], the output is "/home/myusername/public_html".

I'm able to get to the inc/ directory by this:

```
$temp_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$temp_path = str_replace('public_html', '', $temp_path);
include_once $temp_path . "/inc/constants.inc.php";
```

but is this a good idea? Am I wrong to worry about having the constants in the public_html folder?

Comment: I suggest you move the constants file into your `inc` folder, and instead of doing the whole `str_replace` thing, just give it a relative path (`../constants.inc.php`).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Instead you should define the root directory based by one file, for example in the config file.

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__); //php >= 5.3
```

or

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); // php < 5.3
```

The use the `ROOT` as the base to include other file.

Comment: I tested your answer and it worked for me but if i call some php file using ajax then called file looks like empty nothing inside error or something.